# Covert ObjectId to String SwiftUI Realm object

Tags: swift, kotlin, realm, kotlin-multiplatform, realm-mobile-platform

I have my model called Restaurant:
realm object on kotlin:

```
class Restaurant : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.create()
    var name: String = ""
    var adress: String? = null
}
```

I want to use the _id property. But for that I need to convert to a String in SwiftUI

I tried: `restaurant_id as! String`, it does not work,

Is is related to this post: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/swift-convert-objectid-to-string/121829

No real answers there

Any other solutions?
the error when using .toHexString():  `Value of type 'any Library_baseObjectId' has no member 'toHexString'`:

[image]

the type of _id in this case:
[image]

The error when trying: `"\(restaurant._id.stringValue)"`

[image]

Comment: First see my answer below but second, what do you want to do with the ObjectId string? You can often use a reference to the object itself instead of converting values to strings.

Comment: I want to send the _id as a parameter to another view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a getter to the class:

```
class Restaurant : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.create()
    var name: String = ""
    var adress: String? = null

    fun getID() : String{
            return _id.toString()
        }
}
```

Comment: Great! Glad my suggestion of `toString()` worked! Upvote for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

ObjectID's in Swift have a stringvalue property which returns the ObjectID as a string

You could do this

```
let idAsAsString = someRealmObject._id.stringValue
```

Or for kotlin and other SDK;s
let idAsString = object._id.toString()

In SwiftUI, the id can be accessed in a similar way, and then use the value to init a new string

```
let x = someRealmObject._id.stringValue
let y = String(stringLiteral: x)
let _ = print(x, y)
Text("\(x) \(y)")
```

and the output will be

```
6376886a1dbb3c142318771c 6376886a1dbb3c142318771c
```

in the console and the same in the Text in the UI

Here's some SwiftUI showing the use

```
List {
    ForEach(myModel) { model in
        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(navigationViewIsActive: $navigationViewIsActive, selectedEntryToShow: model))
        {
            Text("\(model._id.stringValue)") //ormodel._id.toString()
        }
        
    }
}
```

This Swift model works perfectly and the string of ObjectId can be read per above.

```
class Restaurant: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var adress: String? = null
}
```

Comment: In swiftui, it does not translates to ObjectId, but to `Library_baseObjectId`, so in this case stringValue will not work..

Comment: @DhanDaniel My apologies - I overlooked the SwiftUI. I updated the answer for both Swift and SwiftUI

Comment: It still give the same error, I updated the original post with the print and the entire code: `Value of type 'any Library_baseObjectId' has no member toHexString`

Comment: @DhanDaniel I think you responded to the wrong answer, lol. Either way toHexString is not Swift syntax or a function. There's no reason to use Hex anyway - you can just use the String as shown in my answer.

Comment: same for string, I attached a photo, same issue with stringValue, you can see the photo at top

Comment: @DhanDaniel Is this Kotlin or Swift? That's Swift in the question.. I updated my answer with a SwiftUI Realm model... does that work?

Comment: This is Kotlin multi platoform, the objects are in kotlin, but the code that I wrote is swiftui

Comment: @DhanDaniel Did you try [ObjectId.toString()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/)?

Comment: I created a getter on the class

Comment: @DhanDaniel If that's working, please post it as an answer as I believe it would be helpful to others.